# Guide me run SetState() when screen off in flutter

Tags: flutter

**Guide me run SetState() when screen off in flutter.
Sorry my english is bad!**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the help pages, take the SO tour, read about how to ask good questions, as well as this question checklist. Lastly please learn how to create a minimal reproducible example to show us, with emphasis on the minimal part.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need `setState` when screen is off. When you open screen again, it will refresh state automatically

Comment: but i want setstate() run on screen off

Comment: if you explain exactly what u want, maybe we can help you for alternative plan.
Because using `setState` when screen off is unreasonable,

Comment: I use https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter plugin, when play in screen off, end this song to next song is call setsate() to set youtube_id new and play new song, but setstate() not run and not next song until screen on

Comment: You need to use background tasks, see [Executing background tasks with dart](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124)